# What does "ended my own" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> And what was her name, this woman whose life has **ended my own**?

What does it means?

Comment: This is not idiomatic English - where did you find it?

Comment: @StoneyB I edited my lines.

Comment: You really need to provide more context than a single sentence.  The sentence is odd and the meaning will relate to whatever it came from.

Comment: This woman's life has ended my life. What was her name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And what was her name, this woman whose life has ended my own?

That sounds poetic. Basically it means something along the lines of:

> Who was that [expletive deleted] who broke my heart?

In poetry, having ones life ended by a woman is idiomatic to having your heart torn out and stomped on unmercifully.